# How do I call a stored procedure exposed as an Entity Framework Function Import through ADO.NET Data Services (Astoria)?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, wcf-data-services

I've created an Entity Data Model and imported several stored procedures as Function Imports.  I'm exposing the EDM through ADO.NET Data Services (ANDS).  Does ANDS automatically expose the functions through its REST API, or do I need to manually add operations to the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to expose the sproc through a ServiceOperation.  From what I can tell, all mapping to a FunctionImport does is make it usable within the service via CurrentDataSource.  Think of it as only a link between the concept and store.